# Using flexmojos maven plugin to build AIR mobile application

Tags: maven, air

I have dial with AIR mobile application based on 's:ViewNavigatorApplication'.
I use Apache Flex SDK 4.10 and Flexmojos plugin 6.0.1 and JetBrains IDEA 12.1.4

I made 'pom.xml', added 'air-framework' dependencies. The IDE imported it successfully and made the project configuration. The dependencies are shown under the 'Extranl Libraries' node, I can see it. But I don't see ViewNavigatorApplication class, I only see WindowedApplication. The 'pom.xml' loads 'airmobile-config.xml'. When I try to compile it, I get the error 'Error: Could not resolve 's:ViewNavigatorApplication' to a component implementation'. I will soon tear my hair out from my head.

Here is the pom.xml I use.

```
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
     http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <name>Mobile Catalog</name>
    <parent>
      <groupId>com.uni.versal</groupId>
      <artifactId>versal</artifactId>
      <version>2.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <artifactId>mobile-catalog</artifactId>
    <packaging>air</packaging>

    <properties>
      <!--the application name which must match the main mxml file-->
      <!--and application descriptor file names -->
      <application.name>MobileCatalog</application.name>
    </properties>

<build>
<directory>${project.basedir}/target</directory>
<finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
<sourceDirectory>src/main/flex</sourceDirectory>

<resources>
  <resource>
    <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
  </resource>
</resources>

<plugins>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>net.flexmojos.oss</groupId>
    <artifactId>flexmojos-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <extensions>true</extensions>

    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.adobe.flex</groupId>
        <artifactId>compiler</artifactId>
        <version>${flex.version}</version>
        <type>pom</type>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.adobe.air</groupId>
        <artifactId>compiler</artifactId>
        <version>${air.version}</version>
        <type>pom</type>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <configuration>
      <!--<targetPlayer>11</targetPlayer>-->
      <swfVersion>13</swfVersion>
      <flexBuilderCompatibility>true</flexBuilderCompatibility>
      <loadConfig>${settings.localRepository}/com/adobe/flex/framework/framework/${flex.version}/configs_zip/airmobile-config.xml</loadConfig>
      <sourceFile>${application.name}.mxml</sourceFile>
      <descriptorTemplate>${basedir}/src/main/flex/${application.name}-app.xml</descriptorTemplate>
      <!--<configurationReport>true</configurationReport>-->

      <keystore>${project.basedir}/mobile_catalog.p12</keystore>
      <storepass>asdf</storepass>

      <!--optionally include files in the AIR package -->
      <includeFileSets>
        <fileSet>
          <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
          <includes>
            <include>*.*</include>
          </includes>
        </fileSet>
      </includeFileSets>

      <storepass></storepass>
      <contextRoot>versal</contextRoot>
      <!--<localesCompiled>-->
        <!--<locale>en_US</locale>-->
        <!--<locale>ru_RU</locale>-->
      <!--</localesCompiled>-->
      <localesSourcePath>src/main/locales/{locale}</localesSourcePath>

      <defines>
        <property>
          <name>CONFIG::debug</name>
          <value>true</value>
        </property>
        <property>
          <name>CONFIG::release</name>
          <value>false</value>
        </property>
      </defines>

      <debug>true</debug>
      <optimize>false</optimize>
    </configuration>

    <executions>
      <execution>
        <goals>
          <goal>sign-air</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
</plugins>
</build>

<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.adobe.flex.framework.air</groupId>
    <artifactId>air-framework</artifactId>
    <version>${flex.version}</version>
    <type>pom</type>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 0):

RESOLVED: Officially Flexmojos doesn't support AIR mobile applications. That's all.